# Rails: How to get value from selected options and set the value to a non model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, selected

I want to display a selected option in the web page and then get the selected value from user and set this value to a non model attribute. 
The code:

```
<%= select_tag "Choice", options_for_select(["Yes","No"]), :include_blank => true %>
```

In my model project.rb I define a attribute called flag like this.

```
attr_accessor :flag
attr_accessible :flag
```

Coulde anyone tell me how to get the selected value "Yes" or "No" and set the value to flag?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks Marek for the format.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `form_for`, change your select_tag to this:

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :flag, "Choice" %>
  <%= f.select :flag, ["Yes","No"], :include_blank => true %>
<% end %>
```

This will render a select tag with the appropriate name which will submit the value of flag within `params[:project]`, assign that to your model and it should receive the virtual attribute `flag`.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by assigning that to my model? How can I do that? I know a little about rails, just started to learn.

Comment: When you submit that form the params will now include that flag. So when you do Project.new params[:project] the flag value will get assigned because it is within params[:project]. That's it. In your controller when you do Project.new param[:project] or project = Project.find(params[:id]); project.update params[:project], that is what I mean by assign. Hope that helps.